# PHPStorm font rendering on Mac OS

Tags: macos, fonts, phpstorm, antialiasing

I have a problem with PHPStorm IDE. I just switched from Sublime and noticed that the same fonts in PHPStorm look different from Sublime Text editor.

Below you can see how it looks in Sublime and PHPStorm, and you can notice that in PHPStorm the font is very ugly.

**Sublime Text (font_face: Menlo, font_size: 12):**
[image: Sublime text]

**PHPStorm 9 (font_face: Menlo, font_size: 12):**
[image: PHPStorm 9]

How do I fix font rendering in PHPStorm IDE?

Comment: Ugly has no meaning, which of the two is rendering the font *correctly* based on what it's supposed to look like according to the people that make it?

Comment: I dont see difference in fonts

Comment: Okay. I will try to explain for you. I used same color scheme in both editors. In PHPStorm font is blurry and thin.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the *font_options* on Sublime Text, it will look as blurry as on PhpStorm. Then you'll have a uniform rendering. This worked great for me. I hope that helps.